# Support for a permanent clipped AppDrawer

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to make a permanent clipped navigation drawer with Material UI as per  https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Seems that there is a pull request out for this but not yet merged: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/6878

At this stage I'm trying to override with styles but can not get my left nav (paper) to apply the style `marginTop: '50px',`

Are there some samples out there on how to achieve this with v1.0.0-alpha.21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed the way you have to override certain styles in v1. The inline styles no longer work. Certain parts of a component can be overridden with a simple className applied to the component. See this link for further details https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/overrides.

Some deeper nested properties of certain components i.e the height of the Drawer can only be accessed by overriding the class itself. In this case the paper class of the drawer element.

This is a simple example

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Drawer from "material-ui/Drawer";
import { withStyles, createStyleSheet } from "material-ui/styles";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const styleSheet = createStyleSheet("SideNav", {
  paper: {
    marginTop: '50px'
  }
});

class SideNav extends Component {
  ....
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        classes={{paper: this.props.classes.paper}}
        docked={true}
      >
      ....
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

SideNav.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styleSheet)(SideNav);
```

Comment: Hmm...I've done an class override as per the CSS API in the docs for Drawer but I've must have missed something.. so, I'll try exactly as per your code.. thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!